# How to handle unsuccessful Logout in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

In my Spring Security I don't invalidate session immediately, but I am doing it in LogoutSuccessHandler (need to keep some informaiton for post-logout survey)
**This gets me to the point: how should I invalidate session if logout goes wrong?**

**HttpSecurity:**

```
        http.authorizeRequests()
                ...
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(false) // session invalidated by logoutSuccessHandler.
```

**And myLogutSuccessHandler() :**

```
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        ....

        // Invalidation of an old session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            logger.debug("Invalidating session: " + session.getId());
            session.invalidate();
        }

        ...

        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

**This gets me to the point: how should I invalidate session if logout goes wrong?**

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look at this, if it works for you - http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-invalidate-a-spring-security-session/3644/

Comment: Are you using any custom `LogoutHandler`s?

Comment: @NatFar No custom `LogoutHandlers` in that code

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc:

> LogoutHandler implementations expect to be invoked to perform necessary cleanup, so should not throw exceptions.

So your `LogoutSuccessHandler` will always get called. As long as no exception is thrown in your `onLogoutSuccess(..)` method before you actually invalidate the session (or as long as it's caught), your code will always run.

Perhaps the name of the method `onLogoutSuccess()` is not very intuitive (maybe more like `afterLogout()`) . There is no `LogoutFailureHandler` because logging out will **always** succeed and so the `LogoutSuccessHandler`'s `onLogoutSuccess()` will always be invoked.